# Triangulo de números java

Tags: java

Tengo un ejercicio que me pide sacar un triángulo de números con la siguiente estructura:

```
    1
   232
  34543
 4567654
567898765
```

Tengo un problema al hacer que los números decrezcan por la mitad, mi código es el siguiente:

```
        int num = 5;
        int cont = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        cont +=2;
            for (int j = 0; j < num-i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        } 
            for (int k = i; k < cont; k++) {
                System.out.print(k);
            }
            for (int l = i; l < cont-1; l++) {
                System.out.print(l);
            }

        System.out.println("");
        }
```

Y el resultado que me imprime es el siguiente:

```
    1
   232
  34534
 4567456
567895678
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casi lo tenías, si te fijas, en el for donde pintas la parte final de la linea, el valor tiene que decrecer y lo que haces es aumentarlo, además, empiezas desde i hasta cont-1 y es al revés:

```
int num = 5;
int cont = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    cont +=2;
    for (int j = 0; j < num-i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    } 
    for (int k = i; k < cont; k++) {
        System.out.print(k);
    }
    for (int l = cont-2; l >= i; l--) { //Lo inicias a cont-2 hasta i y decrementas su valor
       System.out.print(l);
    }

    System.out.println("");
}
```